# If I invoke a parent's method in parent class, does it invoke child class method with the same name

Tags: java

I want to know whether a child class calling parent method that invokes an overloaded method in the parent class, will invoke the overloaded method in the child class

```
class Parent {

    void doStuff() {

    }

    void asd() {
        doStuff();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void doStuff() {
        // implementation
    }
}

static void main(Args... args) {
    new Child().asd(); -> does this invoke the doStuff with the implementation or the empty doStuff in the parent class?
}
```

Comment: print something in there and you´ll know..

Comment: This invokes the `Child#doStuff()` method. Why don't you try to debug it? :)

Comment: Because I am in the middle of a very broken situation and unbuildable project.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I am calling a parent method from the child class. In the parent method there is a call to a parent method that is also overriden in the child class. My question is will the overriden method in the child class be called as well

Comment: Only your child class method would be called, unless you used `super.doStuff();` inside your child class method

Comment: @Draken so if I have 2 types of Children classes, I can leave the base method empty and the parent class will polymorphically call the child doStuff depending on what the Child is, right?

Comment: Correct, might want to read up on inheritance, check here for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Comment: does it matter if I will leave the method empty or make it abstract?

Comment: Abstract means your child classes have to override it and implement it and should be better if you always want to have something in `doStuff` from your child classes. If you don't, you can leave an empty method in `Parent`, but it seems unnecessary

Comment: Thank you a lot, @Draken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Parent{
    void doStuff(){
       System.out.println("parent class");
    }
    void asd(){
    doStuff();
    }
 }
 class Child extends Parent(){

       @Override
       void doStuff(){
         //super.asd();
         System.out.println("child class");
    }
 }
```

/**
*  When you run the program you will see the two methods being called
*  one from the parent class and then the override method for child.
*  just uncomment the super.asd() in childs doStuff() to see both print.
**/

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Child c = new Child();
    c.doStuff();  // call methods
}
```